Failed to apply plugin 'com.liferay.workspace'
Liferay randomly can't build gradle
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.liferay.workspace'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace.WorkspaceExtension.
> Unable to get product info for :dxp-7.3-sp1`

I removed .gradle folder, re-import project, & re-install intellij but the issue still exist, no settings changed before this issue

There was a server outage yesterday - maybe it's that? Does it work again?

Idk if that was because the liferay repository issue, build success in the next day without change any settings, but today I just found this issue again "Unable to get product info for :dxp-7.3-sp1"

if you're referencing releases.liferay.com: Change that to releases-cdn.liferay.com/. Liferay's IT team is in the process of moving the repository to a more reliable infrastructure. There was another outage today - I didn't follow if it was fixed or not.

Thanks for the insight @OlafKock, now gradle build already work again
